# Applying a pattern to a matrix in Octave

Tags: matrix, octave

I am working with Octave. I have a random MxN matrix. I want to set certain values within the matrix to zero using a predefined pattern:

```
Matrix:           Pattern:        Result:
[45 88 93 25 23     [1 0            [45  0 93  0 23 
 13 55  4 90  9      0 0]             0  0  0  0  0
 34 87 67 07 88                      34  0 67  0  9 
 13 57 14 16 27                       0  0  0  0  0
 94 35 68 22 89]                     94  0 68  0 89]
```

How is it possible to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: So the pattern matrix should simply be repeated in both directions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two solutions:

Using [`repmat`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/repmat.html):

```
ms = size(Matrix);
ps = size(Pattern); 
P = repmat(Pattern, ceil(ms ./ ps));    % repeat the pattern
result = Matrix .* resize(P , ms);      % resize and apply the pattern
%result = Matrix .* P(1:ms(1),1:ms(2)); % same as above
```

Using [`im2col`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/image/function/im2col.html) and [`col2im`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/image/function/col2im.html) from the image package:

```
pkg load image
ms = size(Matrix)
ps = size(Pattern)
col = im2col(Matrix,ps,'distinct');        % convert image to columns
colpat = col .* Pattern(:);                % apply the pattern 
result = col2im(colpat, ps,ms,'distinct'); % convert column back to image
```